# Untabify not making changes in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have some old source code which uses tabs as white space (\t), and some newer code after we changed our source code convention which uses 4 spaces instead. Those two look the same on Windows just fine, but on Linux in Vim a tab is 8 spaces, so new code with 4 spaces and old code with 8 spaces looks all funky.

I tried to untabify the source files, and check them in, but the TFS update just completely ignores those, and I get nothing changed when checking in. How can I check in the change from Tab to 4 spaces?

Answer (score 0):

This may due to your Visual Studio side setting and thus the changes could not be display.

For the mixed tabs and spaces , try to change your visual studio text editor setting. You can decide if you want visual studio to insert spaces or tabs here:

**Tools/Options/ -> Text Editor/All Languages/Tabs, select the "Keep Tabs" option.**

[image]

After setting this, the **tab** will changed as `→` instead of `-`like space.

Comment: No, I definitely change it in the source code from tabs to spaces, but when checking it in, it gets reversed.

Comment: @SinisterMJ Gets reversed？ Sound impossible, you mean TFS not get the changes you have don in locally? Based on the test in myside, TFS actually detect the changes (change tab to space) in the source control folder, otherwise it will not list in pending changes. After check in, the changes still exist in the server, you could **compare changesets** of the one changed and the original version  with diff tool. It will show the difference.

Comment: @SinisterMJ Any update on this? After double checked again, this shouldn't be a sever side issue. Suggest you double check your local environment and make sure your changes in the local also checked successfully in TFS.